# git submodules dirty state

Tags: git, git-submodules

For the sake of this discussion assume I have two repos on github: foo_top and bar_submodule. As suggested by the naming bar_submodule is a submodule of foo_top.

I have both repos cloned into my local working directory. Recently I went into the bar_submodule, created a new branch and made a change then pushed it to the remote.

When I go into foo_top and do

```
git status
```

I see a message that says I've got local changes not committed:

```
modified:   deps/bar_submodule (modified content)
```

and so I do a diff and see:

```
diff --git a/deps/bar_submodule b/deps/bar_submodule
--- a/deps/bar_submodule
+++ b/deps/bar_submodule
@@ -1 +1 @@
-Subproject commit e851c59f8262bfbd8c2e1c0d3471494cf6c8475f
+Subproject commit e851c59f8262bfbd8c2e1c0d3471494cf6c8475f-dirty
```

The -dirty part confuses me. In the bar_submodule repo, on the branch I did my work on, I see a valid sha for the commit. I was expecting that sha to show up in the output of the git diff where the -dirty version is.

if I cd into deps/bar_submodule and do a git diff there I see the changes I made in the other repo shown in there as needing to be added.

Someone told me to just do `git add deps/bar_submodule` from the root of the foo_top repo and I tried that but nothing changed--there was nothing to add/commit/push and the result of git diff didn't change.

I have a few questions:

1. What is the deal with the -dirty? Why isn't the real commit sha in there?
2. Do I need to add, commit and push those changes from with in the deps/bar_submodule directory of the foo_top repo?
3. Should I have just made these changes in the deps/bar_submodule directory instead of doing it from a clone of the bar_submodule directory in the first place?

Comment: You say *Recently I went into the bar_submodule, created a new branch and made a change then pushed it to the remote* but then in item 3 start with *Should I have just made these changes in the deps/bar_submodule directory instead of doing it from a clone of the bar_submodule directory*. What does that first declaration mean, then? You "went into" = "made a clone elsewhere and did not go into"?

Comment: sorry, what I meant was that I have both repositories cloned onto my machine. The first statement meant that I cd'd into the ~/bar_submodule directory, not the ~/foo_top/bar_submodule directory. Once I was in there I created a git branch and worked with it in the standard git workflow. My 
question in number 3 is should I be working directly in foo_top/bar_submodule to make changes that I add/commit/push right from that directory instead of the clone of bar_submodule that isn't in the foo_top repo/directory

Comment: OK. So the real mystery at this point is why, if you did this work in `~/bar_submodule` (clone H-for-home) and not in `~/foo_top/bar_submodule` (clone B-for-bar), B has any modifications at all to its index and/or work-tree (which is what the `-dirty` implies).

Comment: yep, that is definitely part of the mystery and I don't have a good answer for how it got that way. what I ended up doing is blowing out my foo_top repo locally  (rm -rf foo_top) recloning, setting up and then just making my changes in foo_top/bar_submodule and every thing works much better. my mistake was ever working in ~/bar_submodule in the first place.